# Play midi alongside animation

Tags: python, animation, keyframes, animation-nodes

my goal is to play exact midi note in a certain frame, so i thought the only way is to use a midi in/out python library, and execute a certain python command line or script in the required keyframe, so from here my question becomes: is there any way to keyframe a python script? 
of course if there are any other easier ways for my goal, it would be better

Comment: There is currently no intuitive way to use Midi in Animation Nodes. But the the developer has done some testing of such system: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhUS13dzF5A
So there might be support of midi data in AN at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do that, but you shouldn't need to. Try simply exporting the MIDI to a sound file, and using the Video Sequence Editor (I think) to align it with your animation.

Comment: i saw it implemented here on this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFUtjWTIOEM

he says he used blender's game engine, but i have no clue how to start, as he gave no further explanations. and of course i considered the idea of saving it to a file and aligning it to video, but it doesn't suit my project

Comment: Oh, like in real time? Interesting! Well, I have no idea how to do that. (: But if you want that, you shouldn't really need keyframes—you just need to have a MIDI note trigger an animation.